# Use "Custom Data Object" for non-Customer/Company related information

Tags: eloqua

When I create Custom Data Object, it asks to set "Default Entity Mapping used in upload". What should I use if I want to store only product information (not who bought what)

Is it possible to create a "Custom Data Object" to store non-Customer/Company related information?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, none of the data has to map back to any contact or account record. Even if it happens to match (unlikely, unless you design it as so), there is no harm to your CDO or contact records.

However, if you're not looking to map it to another record, then what is the use case?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used JSON instead. Product information like Product Name and Product Price to use in Landing Pages for Dynamic Components